# Provide sync between PostgreSQL and NoSQL database

Tags: postgresql, denormalization, nosql

I've got a PostgreSQL DB with very normalized data, so a lot of requests spawn a lot of joins and my DB works slow. I want to denormalize data from PostgreSQL and store it in a NoSQL DB for readonly access. For that I must provide sync between PostgreSQL and NoSQL (little latency is allowed). I want to consider different ways so I can choose the most suitable.

I can use events from models when there were changes and put them into a queue. After that a worker can process events and add necessary data to NoSQL, but I've got a lot of legacy code which is bad quality and I don't want to change it a lot. Also, I can denormalize data and put it to PostgreSQL but don't know if this is suitable solution or not.

What solutions exist for such tasks?

Comment: You may want to check out [foreign data wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#NoSQL_Database_Wrappers).

Comment: @Dmitrii Goldring thanks for advice. I know about foreign data wrapper, but I want to get advice about how I can implement all process from beginning to end. For example, how can I use foreign data wrappers that provide sync? I can use SQL triggers, ORM events, but actually because of a lot of legacy I think better solution could be don't change legacy code and maybe work with DB replication or binary log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I did research on this topic and I've got results.
There are several ways to solve this task. I tell you about 3 general ways.**

**1)** You can use signals(ORM signals for example) in your app to get notifications about changes.
You should put it to queue, RabbitMQ if changes are not a lot and Kafka if there are a lot of changes. It's a simple solution for not complicated apps which were good written.

**If you have complex architecture and a lot of legacy then you should choose this approach:**

General meaning about this approach is [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/bottled-water-real-time-integration-of-postgresql-and-kafka/)

**2)** Use PostgreSQL [logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/logicaldecoding-explanation.html) to get events about changes, it's very powerful feature. I found two solution where was used this feature: **1.** Use tool [bottledwater](https://github.com/confluentinc/bottledwater-pg) with Kafka, it works, but not develop any more. **2.** Use tool [debezium](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/), it works and has active community.

**3)** Use PostgreSQL [logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/logicaldecoding-explanation.html) to get events about changes and write own tool to get events.

Comment: what nosql did you choose to work with postgresql? have you thought about graph database like Neo4j ?

Comment: @stackdave, it depends only of your tasks. I needed DB to store denormalized data as document, so MongoDB is perfect for that task. if you need to work with data which has complex connections with each other, then Neo4j is your choice.